# Is a flat coherent sheaf over a connected noetherian scheme already a vector bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a connected noetherian ring (not necessarily irreducible), $M$ be a finitely presented flat $A$-module. Then $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a free $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$-module for each $\mathfrak{p} \in  \operatorname{Spec}(A)$.

Is it also true that $M$ is locally free in the sense that we find a generating system $f_1,...,f_n$ of $A$ such that the $M_{f_i}$ are free? When trying to come up with a proof, I needed that $A$ is irreducible, so I wonder if there is a counterexample if $A$ is reducible?

Comment: "a generating system $f_1,\dotsc,f_n$ of $M$ such that the $M_{f_i}$ are free?" - What is $M_f$ for an element $f$ of $M$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $f_i \in A$ of course. Typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a standard fact in commutative algebra that, for an *arbitrary* commutative ring $A$, an $A$-module $M$ is finitely presented flat if and only if $M$ is finitely genertated projective if and only if $M$ is locally free of finite rank (:= there are elements $f_1,\dotsc,f_n \in A$ generating the unit ideal such that $M_{f_i}$ is finite free over $A_{f_i}$ for each $i$). A proof can be found in books on commutative algebra, and also in the [stacks project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00NV). It follows that for an arbitrary scheme $X$ the flat $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules of finite presentation coincide with the locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules of finite rank.

Comment: Thank you, I had 'forgotten' that in Lemma 10.75.2 in your link $(6)$ resp $(7)$ also hold. We had tried to spontaniously prove it using $(4)$ and it turned out not to be obvious when you don't ask for $A$ to be irreducible, so I wondered.